# image overlay on a video frame using video for linux

Tags: linux, video

I am trying to overlay an image and a time stamp on a video stream which is encoded and streamed simultaneously, I have to add overlay in the captured video frames because the gstreamer plugins for overlay is causing a frame drops and high cpu usage.

Please let me know whether we can overlay the image on a video frame at the V4l driver level.

My platform is imx53 and the linux kernel version in 2.6.53.

Regards,

Jis